# It is this identity OK? (sum of two resolvent matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, matrix-equations

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ a diagonalizable stable matrix (all eigenvalues have a negative real part) and consider the difference of its resolvent matrix evaluated at symmetric points on the complex line
\begin{align}
&(j\omega I -A)^{-1} - (-j\omega I -A)^{-1} \cr
=& (j\omega I -A)^{-1} + (j\omega I +A)^{-1} 
\tag{a}
\end{align}
I have arrived to the following expression
$$
(j\omega I -A)^{-1} + (j\omega I +A)^{-1}  = -2j\omega (I\omega^2 +A^2)^{-1}
\tag{b}
$$
Is the following proof ok?

**Proof:**
Because $A$  have no eigenvalues on the pure imaginary line, the expression in (a) is analytic. Now we use the following expression to evaluate matrix analytic functions
\begin{equation}
f(A) = \frac{1}{2j\pi}\int_{\Gamma} (zI-A)^{-1} f(z) dz
\tag{c}
\end{equation}
where $\Gamma$ is a closed contour which encloses the spectrum of $A$. We have
\begin{align}
(j\omega I -A)^{-1} + (j\omega I +A)^{-1} &= \frac{1}{2j\pi}\int_{\Gamma} (zI-A)^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{j\omega - z} +\frac{1}{j\omega + z}\right) dz\cr
&= \frac{1}{2j\pi}\int_{\Gamma} (zI-A)^{-1} \left(\frac{-(j\omega+z)-(j\omega-z)}{\omega^2 + z^2}\right) dz\cr
&=\frac{1}{2j\pi}\int_{\Gamma} (zI-A)^{-1} \left(\frac{-2j\omega}{\omega^2 + z^2}\right) dz \cr
&=-2j\omega(I\omega^2 + A^2)^{-1}
\end{align}
It is quite strange to manipulate matrices as scalars, but the proof seems good for me. Can somebody find another proof? Is this expression right?

Here is a plot of the error for this identity made in Matlab with a random stable matrix.

[image]

Comment: You will find another proof in (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1092526) by taking $w=-1$ (primitive square root of unity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure can get more elementary:
$$
\begin{split}
(j\omega I-A)^{-1}+(j\omega I+A)^{-1}
&=
(j\omega I-A)^{-1}[(j\omega I+A)+(j\omega I-A)](j\omega I+A)^{-1}
\\&=
2j\omega(j\omega I-A)^{-1}(j\omega I+A)^{-1}
\\&=
2j\omega[(j\omega I+A)(j\omega I-A)]^{-1}
\\&=
2j\omega[-\omega^2I-A^2]^{-1}
\\&=
-2j\omega[\omega^2I+A^2]^{-1}.
\end{split}
$$